# edit parameters before RunTime

Tags: anylogic

My problem is as follows:
I am modeling a hospital department, specifically the Radiology department which consists of X CT rooms Y X-ray rooms etc.
Is there any way to set these values ( X and Y) before the simulation starts? With a slider or a similar button in the anylogic interface? I know how to do it at run time, but I don't know how to set these parameters before it starts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. Go to the simulation window and add variables called X and Y (they don't necessarily need to be the same names as the parameters but it's easier for reference). Then, in the properties of the simulation window, you have the list of all parameters in main. Set the value of X as X and Y as Y (noting that the first X and Y in my sentence refer to the parameters in main and the second ones refer to the variables in the simulation window).

After that, add a slider in the simulation window (or any other interface object) and link it to your variables.

Also make sure to uncheck "Skip experiment screen".

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's possible that I haven't the list of parameters in the properties of the simulation window?

Comment: Typically, any parameter you add in main, automatically appears in the simulation experiment properties under parameters. So 1) check the parameters are added in main (as parameters not variables); 2)  check you are in the correct properties window and that the parameters tab is not collapsed... Send a screenshot if you want of your parameters and of your simulation experiment properties.

Comment: Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd8QMBL-ri4